Swift animation stopped working in iOS 18
Swift animation stopped working in iOS 18.   The animation should move an image and change opacity at the same time.  On iOS 18 the image doesn't appear and likely goes straight to opacity 0.0.   Any ideas what changed in iOS 18?
@State private var imageAlignment = Alignment.topTrailing
@State var opac: Double = 1.0

  var body: some View {
                    ZStack {
                                ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: true) {
                                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                        BulletList(listItems: listString, listItemSpacing: 20, bulletWidth: 15)
                                            .scaledFont2(name: "Poppins-Medium", size: 20)
                                            .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 0, x: 1, y: 1)
                                    }
                                    .padding(15)
                                }  //end scrollview
                                .background(
                                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 17)
                                        .fill(Color(red: 179 / 255, green: 140 / 255, blue: 237 / 255))
                                        .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 0, x: 1, y: 1))
                                .padding(.horizontal, horizPadding)
                                .padding(.vertical, 10)
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                                .padding(.bottom, 40)
                                ///animation goes here
                                
                        Image("number-one")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                            .padding(.horizontal, 50)
                            .padding(.vertical, 20)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: imageAlignment)
                            .opacity(opac)
                            .onAppear {
                                withAnimation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 3).repeatCount(2, autoreverses: false)) {
                                    imageAlignment = .bottom
                                } completion: {
                                    opac = 0.0
                                }
                            }
                        } //end ZStack
}


I fail to understand why this would animate the opacity at all. opac = 0.0 isn't even in the animation block.

I can reproduce on neither iOS 17.4 nor iOS 18.0. On both versions, the image appears and its position is animated twice. After that, it disappears without animation.

Thanks @Sweeper, I added the rest of the code.  For some reason placing the code in the ZStack so the animation runs above the text/background overlay seems to be causing the issue in iOS 18

If I comment out the "//ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: true) {" line it works.   Not sure why the ScrollView causes the animation not to work
